# How do I change the subnet of a secondary NIC in Azure

Tags: azure, subnet

I have a VM with 3 NICs that was deployed from the Marketplace.
I need to change the subnets and IP addresses that are currently assigned to NICs 2 & 3
I have tried using PowerShell scripts but receive this error:
Set-AzureRmNetworkInterface : Cannot change subnet of network interface /subscriptions/xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx
4999/resourceGroups/vcfrg/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/vm200-eth1 while it is in use as a
secondary network interface.

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: What happens if you try and do it through the portal? You should be able to go to the NIC object, then IP Address, and then set the subnet

Answer (score 1):

I had create a VM with two NICs, NIC01(10.0.1.0/24) and NIC02(10.0.2.0/24), then I use powershell to set the azure network interface, here is my script, after the script complete, the NIC01 change to 10.0.3.0/24. It works for me.

```
$NICname = nic01
$RGname = jason
$NIC = Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $NICname -ResourceGroupName $RGname
$NIC.IpConfigurations[0].PrivateIpAddress 
$VNET = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name $VNETname  -ResourceGroupName $RGname
$Subnet2 = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -VirtualNetwork $VNET -Name subnet03
$NIC.IpConfigurations[0].Subnet.Id = $Subnet2.Id
Set-AzureRmNetworkInterface -NetworkInterface $NIC
```

[image]

And here is the result:
[image]

Comment: @Scott Here a good article about how to change Subnet and Virtual Network for Azure Virtual Machines (ASM & ARM), refer to the link:https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/igorpag/2016/03/13/how-to-change-subnet-and-virtual-network-for-azure-virtual-machines-asm-arm/

Comment: @Scott Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.